# If $V$ is finite dimensional Hilbert space, is $L^2(0,T;V)$ also finite dimensional?

Tags: hilbert-spaces

If $V$ is finite dimensional Hilbert space, is $L^2(0,T;V)$ also finite dimensional?

I think so, but $L^2$ is infinite dimensional so I am not sure.

Comment: Try $V = \mathbb R$ and $T = 2\pi$.

Comment: @UmbertoP. Your comment could be an answer.